# Figuring out Regex pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

I am still not all that good when it comes to writing Regex patterns and am having issues with trying to figure out a search pattern for the following string:

`{embed_video('RpcF9EYXZpZFBhY2tfRklOQUwuZj','575','352','video_player')}`

I basically need to search a page for anything in between the hash `{}` marks.

I have tried this:

```
string = $(".content").text();
string.match("^{[\w-]}");
```

But its not working... any ideas on what I could be doing wrong?

Thanks for the help everybody! This is what I did to make it work:

```
$("div", "html, body").each(function(){
        var text = $(this).text();

        if(text.match("^\{.*\}$")) {
            console.log("FOUND");
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using eclipse by any chance, there is a regular expression plugin with which you can play around and see how your regular expression searches your text.

I would try this

```
string.match("^\{.*\}$");
```

Answer (score 3):

This should find the innermost content of curly braces (even nested ones).

```
string.match(/\{([^\{\}]*)\}/)[1]; // the [1] gets what is within the parentheses.
```

edit:

Thanks to the comments below here is a cleaner version:

```
string.match(/\{(.*?)\}/)[1];
```

Comment: +1, but you don't need to escape the braces within the character class.

Comment: You can just use a non-greedy version ".*?" instead to keep it cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

One problem is the lack of a quantifier.  As it stands, your regex is looking for a single `\w` or `-` character, denoted by your character class.  You're probably looking for either of the following quantifiers:

- `[\w-]*` - match 0 or more `\w` or `-` characters
- `[\w-]+` - match 1 or more `\w` or `-` characters

Another problem is the restrictions in the character class.  `[\w-]` won't match `(`, `)`, `"`, spaces or other non-word characters that may appear.  If you want to match all characters, use `.`.  If you want to match all characters except `}`, use `[^}]` instead.

For example:

```
string = $(".content").text();
string.match("^{[^}]+}");
```

Using `*` would allow the content within the braces to be empty.

**Side note:** It looks to me like you're gearing up to `eval()` the code contained within the `{` and `}`.  `eval()` is generally best avoided (if possible) for both security and performance reasons.  In your case, you may be able to use this instead:

```
var string = $(".content").text(), fn, args;
if (string.charAt(0) == "{" && string.charAt(string.length - 1) == "}") {
    fn = string.slice(1, string.indexOf("("));
    args = string.slice(string.indexOf("("), string.lastIndexOf(")")).split(",");

    window[fn].apply(null, args);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `"\{.*?\}"`.  But it won't handle the situation with nested curly braces. [Here](http://rubular.com/) you can test your regexps online.

```
string.match("^\{(.*?)\}$")[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

Search for the following regular expression:

```
var sRe = /\{([^\}]*)\}/g;
sText.match(sRe);
```

It means that you are searching for character "{" followed by any symbols but not "}" optionally and then ending with "}".

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to escape the {} characters...they have special meaning in regex...

Comment: also the ^ means start of line so if there is anything before it this wont match.

Comment: I think "^" means starts with. it does not specifically mean start of a line. xxxx { yyyy }, this will be satisfied by that expression.